# How to create Controllers for Simple Table Inheritance domains in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

If I create an abstract class `Document` and then, using [Single Table Inheritence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Table_Inheritance), create its subclasses `Book` and `Email`, should I create a Controller class for each subclass?

If the answer is no, how to inject the service of a specific class (eg. BookService) into the Controller?

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion you should not use a controller for each model class. The reason is that the controller covers the tasks you want to be put together programmatically. Like doing all the tasks for your documents. If you have subclasses like book then these are also documents and you could handle them with the very same controller with almost no new code.

My model classes would look like this:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name="document")
public abstract class Document{
  ...
  Getters and Setters
  ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="book")
public class Book extends Document {
  ...
  Getters and Setters
  ...
}
```

Then you have a controller like this. If you want to use a service inside the controller you can do this e.g. with autowiring the service in spring and annotate it.
The function myFunction1 accepts Documents as well as Books so there is no need to have a second controller.

```
@Controller
public class DocumentController {

  @Autowired
  private YourService yourService;

  public <T extends Document> String myFunction1(T myDocument) {
    String result = yourService.getResult(myDocument);
    return result;
  }

  ...
  further functions 
}
```

Comment: I got it. But a Book have some different properties than an Email. How can I deal with those differences in the DocumentController ?

Comment: Well normally (as you said) you would use a service. In that service you can do the specialization (e.g. with the instanceof operator). I wonder if I would use the class Document as an abstract super class with the subclasses Book and E-Mail. Maybe you could make two simple classes without inheritance.